# RPM %postun seems to have no effect at all

Tags: rpm, yum, specifications, rpmbuild

I'm currently trying to assure that some specific files and folders get deleted once I remove an rpm package for good. So, to make things simple, I just created a file `~/sample.txt` to be deleted on a post-uninstall script.
 So I have this section on my spec file:

```
%postun

if [ "$1" = 0 ];
    then
    rm -f ~/sample.txt
fi
```

The thing compiles, given that typos got warned once I've tried to delete the package but, even when fixed, the postun script seems to not run at all. My suspicion is that since the rpm didn't create the `~/sample.txt` file, it wouldn't be able to delete it either.

Note: the conditional `if [ "$1" = 0 ];` follows a suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398834/rpm-upgrade-uninstalls-the-rpm/8072559#8072559) to avoid deletion on upgrades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing or removing a `rpm` package, the **root** user is executing the commands, so `~/sample.txt` will be expanded to `/root/sample.txt`

PS: a very nice overview for the arguments you get in the pre/post/preun/postun scripts: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/